# Handling multiple stock locations of e-commerce magento site

Tags: magento, location

we have about 2000 products in a store

can we identify where a product's stock is to be picked from for each customer order

from our storehouse.

how to store each products location id and where to store those id's in database using magento..?...

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create custom attribute for product as "location",
In admin panel go to

`Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes`

Create your own attribute for each product and while creating product store the location [location id] etc.

For more information to create custom attribute for product check out this link

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields

and you need to add this custome attribute to quote and order also check this
http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/

Thanks